# Ant + JSON: How to read JSON from a file, modify it then write it back to the file

Tags: json, eclipse, ant

I need to do this using Ant in an Eclipse project:

Read a JSON file (that is located inside my Eclipse project), parse it, so I can make a change on one of the attributes in there, and finally write the resulting JSON back to the same file.

Is this possible? I have tried using an approach of using  with JavaScript, but I can't even reach the file without specifying an absolute path (that I don't want to do, I'd prefer this to be relative to the Ant script.)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Where is the problem? Providing a path to ant script is not difficult. See https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/dirname.html.   Is the problem with json edit? IMHO , you should consider a custom ant task.(http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-writing-tasks.html)